# Java HashTable using Bucket Method

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashtable

How do I search a certain bucket in a hashing solution to find a key? I am having trouble figuring out how to see if my key is already in a given bucket number. I don't understand how to read buckets in an array.

I am writing my own Hash data structure using buckets not Java's.

Comment: Maybe you need to put more detail, e.g., an example would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using Java's built in hash data structures?  Your own?  Usually the ith bucket is just array[i].

Comment: Sorry I should of mentioned that i am writing a custom Bucket Hashing solution

Comment: It will better if you share how are you representing the bucket in the Data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have found the bucket where the item should be, based on hashcode, you will then have to look for the item in question among all the objects in the same bucket. Now all of these objects have the same hashCode, because they are all in the same bucket. So you will have to actually compare these objects with the .equals method to see if the item you are actually looking for is there.

How you manage this group of items that all share the same bucket is up to you. You might have a list, or a sub array, or any data structure that holds a collection of objects.

In fact, you don't necessarily need to hold them all in the same bucket at all. There are schemes called open hashing where items with the same hash 'spill' out of the target bucket, and occupy successive buckets in the top array.

Without knowing your exact data structure I can't be more specific. But basically you use hashCode to get you to the top bucket, then you use equals to find the object within the group of objects that have the same hashcode.